# YouTube API v3 only returning a subset of Channels

Tags: youtube-api

I'm trying to query all of the Channels in a certain Category using the YouTube API v3.  I'm only seeing a subset of the total data though and not the full dataset.

For example if I run

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=snippet&categoryId=GCTXVzaWM&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I get the following response

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#channelListResponse",
  "etag": "\"VL8G1mjP6hNWWlBXDxCr2A3Miyk/yqDRDOUH3lTI0g5E97wJIDVi9H8\"",
  "nextPageToken": "CAUQAA",
  "pageInfo": {
     "totalResults": 201,
     "resultsPerPage": 5
  },
  "items": [ ... ]
 }
```

So you can see I'm only getting 201 channels returned and there are definitely more than 201 music channels on YouTube.  If I go through all of the pages I'm not seeing any channels with less than 100k subscribers.

Should I just use the Search API? Will that even return all the data?  If I should use Search, then what's the point of the Channels API?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs:

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list

... it sounds like 201 might actually be the right number of total results for the request you're making.

> The categoryId parameter specifies a YouTube guide category, thereby requesting YouTube channels associated with that category.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/guideCategories

These are curated by YouTube. If you go to this page at the moment and look for "Music" you'll see there are indeed 201 channels.

http://www.youtube.com/channels

It doesn't look like the /channels call is going to provide what you want. It seems like you may have to use the /search call, and pass a video category id, which you'll probably have to find by looking up the video categories for the US region and picking the one that matches up what you want.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoCategories

> GET
>   https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videoCategories?part=id%2Csnippet&regionCode=US&key={YOUR_API_KEY}

EDIT: Hm... you can't pass video category id unless you pass type=video, so, may not work for a channel search. I don't think you can do what you seem to be trying to do.

Comment: It looks like you're right and we might need to rethink our display concept a bit...  Otherwise I might search and then filter channels from there, though I'm afraid I might hit my API limit.

Thanks!